# Any ideas on how to remove the back part of this fire surround?

Tags: drywall, fireplace

I’m really struggling to remove the back part of my fireplace. It’s made of marble and stuck onto the wall, which is made of plasterboard as far as I can tell.

It seems like it’s stuck on with a type of adhesive which are placed in big blobs in the corners and middle. It’s quite rubbery / pliable.

I’ve tried using a chisel and a hammer, which isn’t making much progress. I’ve also tried sawing through, but that doesn’t really work either. I’m a little worried that I’ll end up ripping big chunks out of the plasterboard.

Any advice would be welcome, photos below.

Fire Surround
[image]

Adhesive
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try piano wire or mason's line (string) in a sawing motion. (Partner helps for this. So does tying a loop and putting a handhold in it, as the pressure you'll need usually hurts bare hands.)

Sadly, you're apt to have to patch the drywall in the end... maybe just a little less if you get lucky.

Answer (score 0):

Big blobs of rubbery/pliable adhesive makes me think "silicone", because other types of adhesive generally cure/dry and get hard.

Unfortunately, the only way to break the bond would be by slicing through it or mechanically tearing it free.

Slicing it would require a long straight thin blade, like a long fillet knife or sharp machete. Then you would still be faced with the task of scraping it from the wallboard, which would likely cause some damage that you would need to repair.

Tearing it loose would probably cause damage to the wallboard like you fear it would.

If it were me, I would probably start at the top and try to slice through the glue while gently pulling/prying the marble outward, working my way down and slicing the glue as best as possible, tearing it away in spots I could not reach to slice.

Either way, I think you should prepare yourself for the inevitable wall repair.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to remove a rubbery adhesive from the surface of drywall without removing some of the drywall surface. Basically, you need to cut through the adhesive, remove the surface material, and then remove the remaining adhesive.

One problem you face is that some adhesive is fairly far from the edge of the face panel. You might consider investing in a [Japanese style flexible pull saw](http://www.homedepot.com/p/DEWALT-Double-Edge-Pull-Saw-DWHT20216/205436902) (sometimes sold as a flush cut saw) that will let you get far behind the face panel. You need help or bracing to prevent the panel from falling as the last of the adhesive is cut.
[image: pull saw]

After the panel is off, remove the remaining adhesive (and inevitably some of the face paper of the drywall), and patch the drywall with drywall compound or setting compound. Sand smooth and paint. It's not as hard as it sounds.

> Images and links for illustration only, not an endorsement of goods or sources